# In SQL if a table have have colums empid,emp,salary,managerid.....Then how we will find a result with colums as employee name, manager name, salary

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

If you are given table given in below structure.

```
empid | empname | salary | managerid
```

How will you find results as

```
empid | empname | salary | managername
```

because manager is also a part of employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self-join, linking the `ManagerId` of the first table (employees) to the `EmpId` of the second use of Employee (managers):

```
SELECT e.empid, e.empname, e.salary
   , COALESCE(m.empname, 'NoManager') AS ManagerName
FROM Employee AS e
LEFT JOIN Employee AS m ON e.ManagerId = m.empId
```

Comment: An 'Inner Join' alone would not work because, if an employee has no manager, this employee will not be shown.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Good point, thank you.  I have updated to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 x.empid,
 x.empname as 'EmployeeName',
 x.salary as 'Salary',
 (SELECT empname FROM Tablename WHERE empid = x.managerid) as 'ManagerName'
FROM
 Tablename x
```